# OpenMP with QT5.3.1 under Qt Creator 3.1.2 under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, openmp

all:

Working Environments:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Qt: 5.3.1
- Qt Creator: 3.1.2
- gcc/g++: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

The entire project is very simple:

1) test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
LIBS += -lgomp -lpthread
```

2) main.cpp

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "omp.h"

void test()
{
    int a = 0;
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        a = i + 1;
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    printf("Time = %d\n", t2 - t1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    clock_t t1 = clock();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        test();
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    printf("Total time = %d\n", t2 - t1);
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The testing results:
1) With #pragma omp parallel for

```
Time = 443989
Time = 448263
Total time = 463749
Time = 226997
```

2) Without #pragma omp parallel for

```
Time = 216945
Time = 208459
Total time = 425435
Time = 208400
```

It seems for me to use OpenMP in this case slows down the entire programs.

However, a different result is given under Windows 8.1 Visual Studio.

Cheers
Pei

Comment: Don't use `clock`. Use `omp_get_wtime`. Compile with optimizations on (e.g. `-O3`) then report your results here.

Comment: Thanks Boson... Just replace clock() by omp_get_wtime(), the result turns to be correct.... Thanks...

Comment: Hey! I'm not just any boson! I'm a pair of [Z bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons)!